# Ending connection Flask after closing browser

Tags: python, flask

I have an application build on Flask that runs on a local machine. How can I end the Flask connection after the user closes the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is too hacky but you could consider opening a socket when a user loads the site.  Then when the socket is closed you perform your exit handler.

Comment: I will try and give you a feedback.